# kern.log: " INFO: task systemd-udevd:295 blocked for more than 120 seconds."

Tags: usb, kernel, systemd, udev

When I cp or dd a ISO (>1GB) file to a usb disk, kernel tell me this. I google it, found it has been going on for years at Launchpad bug reports, why after so many years, it still can't be solved? I used to use Fedora before，it has not such problem.

OS Release: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
kernel: 4.10.0-28-generic & 4.10.0-40-generic (both same problem)

```
Nov 30 23:33:38 UbuntuPC kernel: [ 2417.913106] INFO: task systemd-udevd:295 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
Nov 30 23:33:38 UbuntuPC kernel: [ 2417.913117]       Not tainted 4.10.0-28-generic #32~16.04.2-Ubuntu
Nov 30 23:33:38 UbuntuPC kernel: [ 2417.913121] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
Nov 30 23:33:38 UbuntuPC kernel: [ 2417.913127] systemd-udevd   D    0   295      1 0x00000004
Nov 30 23:33:38 UbuntuPC kernel: [ 2417.913133] Call Trace:
Nov 30 23:33:38 UbuntuPC kernel: [ 2417.913146]  __schedule+0x232/0x700
Nov 30 23:33:38 UbuntuPC kernel: [ 2417.913151]  schedule+0x36/0x80
Nov 30 23:33:38 UbuntuPC kernel: [ 2417.913156]  schedule_preempt_disabled+0xe/0x10
Nov 30 23:33:38 UbuntuPC kernel: [ 2417.913160]  __mutex_lock_slowpath+0x193/0x290
Nov 30 23:33:38 UbuntuPC kernel: [ 2417.913164]  mutex_lock+0x2f/0x40
Nov 30 23:33:38 UbuntuPC kernel: [ 2417.913169]  __blkdev_get+0x6f/0x400
Nov 30 23:33:38 UbuntuPC kernel: [ 2417.913173]  blkdev_get+0x129/0x330
Nov 30 23:33:38 UbuntuPC kernel: [ 2417.913177]  blkdev_open+0x82/0xd0
Nov 30 23:33:38 UbuntuPC kernel: [ 2417.913183]  do_dentry_open+0x208/0x310
Nov 30 23:33:38 UbuntuPC kernel: [ 2417.913187]  ? blkdev_get_by_dev+0x50/0x50
Nov 30 23:33:38 UbuntuPC kernel: [ 2417.913192]  vfs_open+0x4c/0x70
Nov 30 23:33:38 UbuntuPC kernel: [ 2417.913196]  ? may_open+0x9b/0x100
Nov 30 23:33:38 UbuntuPC kernel: [ 2417.913200]  path_openat+0x2ac/0x1430
Nov 30 23:33:38 UbuntuPC kernel: [ 2417.913205]  do_filp_open+0x91/0x100
Nov 30 23:33:38 UbuntuPC kernel: [ 2417.913211]  ? __alloc_fd+0x46/0x170
Nov 30 23:33:38 UbuntuPC kernel: [ 2417.913216]  do_sys_open+0x12d/0x280
Nov 30 23:33:38 UbuntuPC kernel: [ 2417.913222]  SyS_open+0x1e/0x20
Nov 30 23:33:38 UbuntuPC kernel: [ 2417.913227]  entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x1e/0xad
Nov 30 23:33:38 UbuntuPC kernel: [ 2417.913231] RIP: 0033:0x7ff789a25c60
Nov 30 23:33:38 UbuntuPC kernel: [ 2417.913234] RSP: 002b:00007fff8a6c70b8 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000002
Nov 30 23:33:38 UbuntuPC kernel: [ 2417.913239] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000560368fd3cf0 RCX: 00007ff789a25c60
Nov 30 23:33:38 UbuntuPC kernel: [ 2417.913241] RDX: 00005603677f6592 RSI: 00000000000a0800 RDI: 0000560368fd5b90
Nov 30 23:33:38 UbuntuPC kernel: [ 2417.913244] RBP: 0000000000000000 R08: 0000000000000073 R09: 0000000000000003
Nov 30 23:33:38 UbuntuPC kernel: [ 2417.913246] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000000000000
Nov 30 23:33:38 UbuntuPC kernel: [ 2417.913248] R13: 0000560368fd3cf0 R14: 00007fff8a6c7030 R15: 0000000000000000
```